# CSS Transition animation consuming a lot of CPU/GPU

Tags: html, css, performance, css-transitions

I am implementing a small effect on my website. A random size change in one of the DOM elements.

```js
const theDiv = document.getElementById("the-div");

function animate(){
  const value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200); 
  theDiv.style.width = value + "px";    
  
  setTimeout(animate, 200);
}

animate();
```

```css
#the-div { 
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: brown;
  transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="the-div"></div>
```

However, I have realized that using the CSS `transition` property to make the size change smoother is consuming a lot of resources, and I don't want this for such "only aesthetic" effect, but on the other hand, I want to feel free to add such effect to my website.

Here is the CodePen for testing:

- https://codepen.io/d2clon/pen/JjwBbQg

Click the button *"Activate transition"* to activate the CSS transition property.

This is my measures using Mac "Activity Monitor" and opening the CodePen in a Chrome browser:

Transition deactivated:

[image]

Transition activated:

[image]

Using the button *"Add div"* the effect is increased

Am I doing something wrong? Should I not use CSS transitions for these effects? Or should I just ignore this consuming pick because it is normal, expected, and not dramatic?

Comment: Just as an observation, It's taking around 11% of the gpu on my laptop/Windows10/Edge and only 0.4% without the transition.

Comment: Animating width is expensive, as it triggers layout. Have a look here for more details: https://web.dev/animations-guide/#triggers. Try to animate scaleX instead and the performance will be better.

Comment: @JensT it is definitely better (https://codepen.io/fguillen/pen/BavqKLg), sadly the question has been closed for some weird reason. Your comment should be the accepted answer

Comment: You need to include the [mre] in the question itself. Relying on external links like a codepen is not enough.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for the support. I have added the needed code to reproduce the issue in the question itself. is it not visible? I have added a few more details to the code, it should be enough :?

Comment: It's reopened, but would still be better - and easier to answer well - if you could create a runnable snippet as per @MarkRotteveel comment.

Comment: This runs repeatedly perhaps you only want it to run on some event? `setTimeout(animate, 200);` OR perhaps create an animated GIF instead

Comment: @JensT if you add your comment as an answer I will accept it

Comment: I tried @JensT suggestion of scale and found the gpu  usage still 11-12%. What makes it drop significantly is increasing the 200 timeout e.g. to 1000 - but I realise that is not giving the effect you want!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animating width is expensive, as it triggers layout. Have a look here for more details: https://web.dev/animations-guide/#triggers. Try to animate scaleX instead and the performance will be better.

Also it is bad practice to use the ˋallˋ keyword in transition, i would recommend to be more explicit here and use ˋscaleXˋ.

Additionally you could also add ˋwill-changeˋ before triggering the animation, so the browser can prepare for the animation. But you should use it sparingly, if at all. For more details, please see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change?retiredLocale=de (especially the warning at the top)

Also if you want to trigger the animation with js, you may want to have a look at ˋrequestAnimationFrameˋ: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: I tried scale and the GPU usage was about the same as using width. That surprised me. Have you tried it and on what system? I tried on Windows10/Edge.

Comment: It depends on the test case, if it is isolated it will behave different, then in a real webpage. Also animation performance is not always directly related to GPU/CPU usage, depending on the browser, the operating system and other factors. It is more about how the browser works, animations you can promote to their own layer will always be more performant, because they trigger layout & paint in the smallest way possible. So in my opinion it makes more sense to have an eye on the animation framerate, when optimizing, then on system ressources like GPU.

Comment: interesting viewpoint - I was interested in processor usage because of not wanting to flatten the user's battery. Anyway, have you got an example where transform scale uses less processor than changing width? I had assumed it automatically would consume less but haven't been able to create code which shows this. A snippet in your answer which I could run would be great.

Comment: If it is less work for the browser, it automatically results in lower ressource and therefore power consumption. I can't tell you, what you have to change in your test case to make it measurable for you. But this article should give you an idea: https://web.dev/animations-guide/ Maybe also try different browser devtools, firefox has also a great performance panel.

Comment: I wasn't using browser devtools, just WIndows task manager measuring cpu/gpu usage. How much does it go down for you when swapping scale for width?

Comment: I don't use windows, also there is so much other stuff going on, that could influence the os level gpu measurement, i would recommend not going down that path. This seems like a dead end.

Comment: Hmm, the GPU is only showing usage when running this with either scale or width so I can’t see there’s anything else going on (it’s the measurement for Edge only). So, scale is not recommended here, but for reasons I don’t understand!